# How do you find the User Leaderboards

Tags: support, reputation, user-profile

There used to be a link in the user profile that showed what percentile your reputation is. Clicking it took you to the leaderboards for the site. It appears that information has gone away.

Answer (score 2):

click on the "Users" link on the Menu Bar of every page

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users

[image: Leader Board]